# How can an operator be proportional to a scalar?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum

I am an undergraduate physics student reading through some parts of Griffiths's Quantum.

I recently saw that $k$ is proportional to momentum $p$ via the De Broglie relation. But, to my understanding

$$p = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

and $k$ takes on scalar values (for example, in the free particle case $k = \sqrt{\frac{2mE_n}{h^2}}$). How do I reconcile an operator being proportional to a scalar? Or, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What is $k$? In the equation you've posted, both sides are supposed to be operators, not numbers. Why would you think this equation applies to the deBroglie context?

Comment: In case of an eigenvalue equation you have the same thing, for example the Hamiltonian (H) is proportional to the Energy (E) in case of H $\lambda$ =E $\lambda $ It is quite similar, but sometimes an Identity matrix is omitted (although mathematically that would be more proper, but we are physicists so we don't care :D )

Answer (score 3):

There is the momentum operator $\hat p$, which when acting in the $x$-representation is given by the equation you cited.

The eigenstates of the $\hat p$ operator can be labeled by eigenvalue $p$, where $p$ is a real number, i.e. $\hat p |p\rangle = p | p\rangle$

We define the wavenumber $k$ to be $p/\hbar$, so it is a number. You could likewise trivially define the "wavenumber operator" to be $\hat k \equiv \hat p / \hbar$. You recover the usual meaning of wavenumber when the momentum eigenstate is a plane wave with wavelength $\lambda$.

Comment: I think the usual meaning of wavenumber _is_ as an operator.